# UCase specific cells in access

Tags: function, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to change the value inside many fields (only certain field) from lowercase to UPPERCASE in *Access 2007/2013*.

I've made some research and figured it out that is available a function in Access called *UCase*.

Since I'm new to using function in Access, How can I manage to use this function in my dataset without making some trouble?

Comment: Access has fields, not cells. What do you mean by 'some'? Certainly it's possible to modify data via code.

Comment: yeah sorry for this misunderstanding... yes I need to change just some fields, not all the field from the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change data in fields.

Can use UCase in an UPDATE action SQL.

Can either just build a query object and run it or execute SQL action statement in VBA code.

`CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE table SET field = UCase(field)"`

Comment: In SQL, fields are identified by their names.